# Dictionary key does not exist - but it does

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm using `exifread` to get some Exif info from photos.

Currently, I'm trying to get the GPS Latitude and Longitude, which I can do:

```
def main():
    images = image_paths(IMAGE_FOLDER) # folder is say "Sample Photos\\"
    info = {}
    for img in images:
        _lat, _lon = "", ""
        tags = exifread.process_file(open(img,'rb'))       

        for i in tags.keys():
            if i == "GPS GPSLatitude":
                print(i, ":::", tags[i])
```

This prints what I expect, they key name and the values:

> GPS GPSLatitude ::: [32, 52, 66443/1250]
>  GPS GPSLatitude ::: [32, 52,
>   531699/10000] 
> GPS GPSLatitude ::: [32, 52, 531699/10000] 
> GPS
>   GPSLatitude ::: [32, 52, 132789/2500] 
> GPS GPSLatitude ::: [32, 52,
>   265817/5000]

But, to skip doing that loop and just get the key/value pairs quickly, I'm trying instead (this replaces the `for i ...` loop)

```
_lon = tags["GPS GPSLatitude"]
```

But I get an error:

> KeyError: 'GPS GPSLatitude'

How do I access "GPS GPSLatitude" (and "GPS GPSLongitude") without looping through the keys of `tags`?

Edit:

`tags` is `<class 'dict'>`

Comment: Not familiar with `exifread`, what is the `type(tags)`?

Comment: Are you sure _every_ image has the tag? Your output would be compatible with some having it, some not.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: That space appears to be coming from `print`, which automatically prints a space between arguments unless told to do otherwise.

Comment: You only print when that specific image has that tag, but you are looping over multiple images. **Not all images have that tag**, and when they don't you are not printing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Darn it, that's it exactly. I added a `Try/Except` and that fixed it.  Sorry for not catching that earlier :(

Comment: @RuudHelderman - Wow, how didn't that post show up when I searched SO?? That's exactly it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that some of the tags do not have the key `'GPS GPSLatitude'`?

Maybe you can try

```py
_lat = tags.get('GPS GPSLatitude', '')
```

This way, `_lat` will be set to the latitude value if it exists, otherwise it will be set to an empty string.

Comment: Yeah, that's it.  Most *should* have the GPS, which is why I didn't think to check, but apparently not all do.  Thanks!  (Also thanks for teaching me the `get()` function, pretty neat).

Answer (score 0):

If any image doesn't have that tag, you need to handle that exception to prevent the crash. For instance:

```
def main():
    images = image_paths(IMAGE_FOLDER) # folder is say "Sample Photos\\"
    info = {}
    for img in images:
        _lat, _lon = "", ""
        tags = exifread.process_file(open(img,'rb'))       

        try:
            _lon = tags["GPS GPSLongitude"]
            # _lat = tags["GPS GPSLatitude"]  # presumably you also want this
            # do something with these... perhaps add to info
        except KeyError:
            pass  # move on
```

Comment: you have a typo, `_lon` should not be equal to the Latitude variable and its pointless to initiate both variables as empty in each loop if you're just going to overwrite them

Comment: Thanks, @eagle --> was just intended to be an example but good catch on the typo